# WCF on Azure Cloud Services with Azure Website Clients

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding, azure-cloud-services

I cannot seem to find any combination of tutorials or information online to set me in the right direction, so I'm hoping the community can help me out!

I have some experience with WCF in the past (mostly simple/default http implementations), but nothing to the level I am attempting with my current architecture. Unfortunately 99% of the info I'm finding for WCF is a couple of years old, and most of it does not address Azure specific details. Most books are published back in 2007, and do not address the newer IDE/Tooling or WCF updates since that time. Needless to say I have a few open questions, and would love to get pointed in the right direction after exhausting Google, Stack Overflow, MSDN & YouTube!

**In a nutshell:**

- I want to centralize all business logic behind a single WCF service
  on Azure (it will be load balanced on a Cloud Service).
- I have a number of web clients that will be consuming this service.
- All the clients are C#/.NET MVC projects that I control (I do not need or want the
  WCF endpoints to be publicly available)
- I would prefer to whitelist access to the endpoints, rather than
  implement authentication (for performance & simplicity)

**Hear are my questions and potential speed bumps:**

- Is WCF the right solution? Is there a newer better technology I should be using?
- If I use a Cloud Service for my WCF solution, is WebRole or WorkerRole my best option and why? Are hosting the service as a Website an option? (It would save cost)
- In my research I've landed on the fact that using NetTCP binding is faster than using the default Http bindings. But I can't find a simple example of how to set this up using VS 2013/.Net 4.5/Azure Cloud Service. Is there a good tutorial for this? Also, I'm assuming NamedPipes are not on option for me?
- Since all the consumers of the WCF service will be running on Azure Websites, is NetTCP still possible?  How do I create service references? I'm assuming I just use the NetTCP endpoint address, but what about whitelisting for security within the Azure infrastructure?
- How can my Azure Website clients connect to TCP within Azure the fastest? Affinity groups don't seem to be an option for Websites, should I abandon this and deploy all my clients as WebRoles so they can share Affinity with my WCF Service? Is Azure smart enough to know that the website is calling a machine within the same region and keep the connection within the region? How is this ensured?
- I will have a debug, stage and production environment for my WCF service. What is the best way to switch between the various endpoints on my azurewebsite client(s)? I'd prefer to do it during startup in my global.asax file using C#, rather than in my web.config. I only intend to keep one setting in my Web.Config for "Environment". Ideally I will have a Switch() statement in my startup file that will determine with WCF environment endpoint to use for my Service References.

My apologies for the array of questions. I was thinking about breaking this out into multiple posts, but keeping them in the same context seemed to be the only way to ensure that I am communicating the scope of my inquiry.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I found a great series of videos on Microsoft Virtual Academy that answers all of my questions:

[Azure & Services](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/developing-windows-azure-and-web-services)

The key videos in this series are: 1,2 & 7. Here is a direct link to each one:

[Intro to WCF](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/developing-windows-azure-and-web-services/01)

[WCF on Azure](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/developing-windows-azure-and-web-services/02)

[Advanced Topics](http://channel9.msdn.com/series/developing-windows-azure-and-web-services/07)